# How to make Toggle button JS keep working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, togglebutton

I am trying to use a toggle button to change a message, but unfortunately it is not working if you keep pressing.

That is my HTML code:

```js
toggled = true;
togBtn.onclick = function() {
  var text = "SELL"
  if (!toggled) {
    document.getElementById("test1").style.display = "none";
    toggled = true;
  }
  if (toggled) {
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = text;
    toggled = false;
  }
};
```

```css
#newsletter {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #1d3030;
  height: 60px;
}

#newsletter h1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 600px;
}

#newsletter form {
  float: right;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e8491d;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(80px);
  transform: translateX(80px);
}

.on {
  display: none;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

input:checked+.slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .off {
  display: none;
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="test1">BUY</h1>
      <form method="post" action="">
        <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" class="togBtn">
    <div class="slider round">
    <span class="on" name="on" id="on">SELL</span>
    <span class="off" name="off" id="off">BUY</span>
    </div>
    </label>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

I add the variable toggled to be used to change the name in HTML.
The button works for two clicks only, after that, it seen no work anymore.

Comment: Please try and indent your code correctly. This will make it much more likely that people will try and help you.

Comment: I believe that because you are never setting the `display` back to `block` or an attribute like that in the second `if` statement it keeps the element hidden.

Comment: I tried to run your code https://jsfiddle.net/76yhmjq3/1/ and the only problem that I see is that the button jumps up. Is that the problem that you're having?

Comment: Now I see. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
 document.getElementById("test1").style.display="none";
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML="BUY";
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the header to change, just the button, you can remove all of the javascript, and the button will still work, and keep changing when you press it

Answer (score 0):

You're logic was a little off. You need to update the `innerHTML` if `toggle` is `true` or `false`. The element was disappearing because of this line: `document.getElementById("test1").style.display="none";`. On the first click it was `true`, so ran the code: `document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML="BUY";`. On the second click `toggle` equalled `false`, so ran `document.getElementById("test1").style.display="none";` and got rid of the text.

Update your script to this, so that it updates the text value when `toggle` is `true` or `false` respectively:

```js
let toggled = true;
togBtn.onclick = function(){
  if(toggled){
   document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML="SELL";
    toggled = false;
  } else  {
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML="BUY";
    toggled = true;
  }
};
```

```css
#newsletter {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #1d3030;
    height: 60px;
}
#newsletter h1 {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 600px;
}
#newsletter form {
    float: right;
}
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 34px;
}
.switch input {
    display: none;
}
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #e8491d;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(80px);
    transform: translateX(80px);
}
.on {
    display: none;
}
.on,
.off {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
}
input:checked+ .slider .on {
    display: block;
}
input:checked + .slider .off {
    display: none;
}
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="test1">BUY</h1>

      <form method="post" action="">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" class="togBtn">
          <div class="slider round">
            <span class="on" name="on" id="on">SELL</span>
            <span class="off" name="off" id="off">BUY</span>
          </div>
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide explanations with your answers and don't link to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just place a code snippet into your answer.

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Better. Now, please edit the answer so that instead of pointing to a Fiddle, it just has a code snippet that you can run right here.

Comment: Thank you. Don’t forget that SO is a knowledge base, so answers should be as complete and self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write these `if` conditions. You can simply do it using ternary operator on `click` event and change the text like this

```js
togBtn.onclick = function() {
var  obj = document.getElementById("test1");
    obj.innerHTML == "BUY"? (obj.innerHTML = "SELL"):(obj.innerHTML = "BUY");
 
};
```

```css
#newsletter {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #1d3030;
  height: 60px;
}

#newsletter h1 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 600px;
}

#newsletter form {
  float: right;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e8491d;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(80px);
  transform: translateX(80px);
}

.on {
  display: none;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

input:checked+.slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .off {
  display: none;
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="test1">BUY</h1>
      <form method="post" action="">
        <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" class="togBtn">
    <div class="slider round">
    <span class="on" name="on" id="on">SELL</span>
    <span class="off" name="off" id="off">BUY</span>
    </div>
    </label>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so much simpler than you are making it. There's no need for two `span` elements and then toggling the `display` of each. Just use one `span` and update its text based on what the text currently is.

Also, your HTML isn't valid. You're using the `label` element incorrectly.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".slider.round");
var output = document.querySelector(".onOff");
var test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var text = (output.textContent === "Buy") ? "Sell" : "Buy";
  output.textContent = text;
  test1.textContent = text;
});
```

```css
#newsletter {
      color: #ffffff;
      background: #1d3030;
      height: 60px;
}

#newsletter h1 {
      float: left;
      padding-left: 600px;
}

#newsletter form {
      float: right;
}

.switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 115px;
      height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
     position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #e8491d;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
}

    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 26px;
      width: 26px;
      left: 4px;
      bottom: 4px;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
    }

    input:checked + .slider {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }

    input:focus + .slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(80px);
      transform: translateX(80px);
    }

    .onOff {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    input:checked + .slider .on {
      display: block;
    }

    input:checked + .slider .off {
      display: none;
    }

    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<section id="newsletter">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="test1">BUY</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
    
      <!-- You shouldn't use a label here -->
      <div class="switch">
      
        <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" class="togBtn">
        
        <div class="slider round">
          <span class="onOff" name="onOff">Buy</span>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```